# UITabBarItem accessibilityLanguage not working

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uiaccessibility

So I have an app with four tabs.
The language on the tabs (danish) are different from the one on my phone (English).
Handling accessibility in the app, this is of course a case I'd like to handle.
And it works everywhere in the app except for the tab bar items.

Buttons, labels etc. are being read properly in danish, when setting `someItem.accessibilityLanguage` or `someLabel.accessibilityLanguage`.

When I'm trying to do the same with the tab bar items, nothing seems to work.

I've tried `view.tabBarItem.accessibilityLanguage = "da"` + setting `.accessibilityLanguage` on the view itself, the tabBarController, the tabBar and even the navigationController that the view is added to.

Is this intended behaviour from Apple? A bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

When setting `view.tabBarItem.accessibilityLabel` to various texts it works. So it's definitely registering my changes and not just reading the title that is set for the actual label on the tab bar item.